# What does this Account storage map definition mean in the pallet_balances?

Tags: substrate

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
    pub type Account<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        AccountData<T::Balance>,
        ValueQuery,
        GetDefault,
        ConstU32<300_000>,
    >;
```

What does `ConstU32<300_000>` mean here? This definition is from the balances pallet.

Also when are we supposed to declare storage maps as `pub` rather than `pub(super)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does `ConstU32<300_000>` mean here?

This is the maximum number of expected elements in this storage map.

> Also when are we supposed to declare storage maps as `pub` rather than `pub(super)`?

This is just normal rust syntax to tell the compiler who is allowed to access the item. Aka you need to declare it pub when you want to access the item from a different crate.

Comment: I am assuming `super` stands for the `runtime/lib.rs` file?

Comment: `This is the maximum number of expected elements in this storage map.` - Does that mean that one cannot add more than 300_000 keys to this StorageMap?

Comment: `pub(super)` means in the upper module. The current FRAME `pallet` macro requires that the pallet definition is done in its own module, because of some short comings of the current macro system in Rust. So, if you want to use your types defined there in the top level `lib.rs` file (which is just a module as well) you need to tag them as `pub(super)`. However, that means that outside of your crate they are not accessible.

Comment: Yeah the `300_000` is the upper limit of keys in this map. However, I would not see this as the absolute maximum. We are currently working on adapting benchmarking for Parachains and that requires that you have a number of elements you can calculate with. In the future this will probably be changed if there is a need or made configurable.

Comment: I am guessing since `pub(super)` only exposes your types to the upper module, which is runtime/lib.rs in this case, it won't be visible to other pallets, unless we annotate the type with `pub` right?

Comment: If you want to access this from other pallets, you need to use `pub` that is correct.